# How to use previous parameter from array in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, robotics

I have been try to code this, to increment the user input by 33 if the input is "31" or more up to the input or "90", and I have hit a wall where I want to use the user input from the array but I cannot. Could anyone help? Thank you.

```
if (choice.equals("R")) {
    System.out.println("You have selected to draw a Rectangle!");
    System.out.println("Please enter the Height and Width of the rectangle that is within 30cm - 90cm: ");
    int[] array = new int[2];
    int[] array2 = new int[2];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String line1 = scan.nextLine(); 
    String[] numbers1 = line1.split(" "); 
    for(int i=0;i<numbers1.length;i++){
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers1[i]);
    }
```

I am trying to make a method to be able to easily call upon it later on, but that's the problem as I cannot complete my calculation.

```
public static void timeTurn (int a, int b) {

    for(int i = 1000; i < 3001; i+= 33) {

        if(numbers1.equals(>=30)) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the array into your function?  `public static void timeTurn(int a, int b, String[] numbers1) {`.  It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I'm trying to convert cm to milliseconds (1000 to 3000), and I think that making a method would make calling it the easiest. For example, if the user inputs "60" i want the method to increment the 1000 milliseconds by 33 until 2000 is reached; if that makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me converting a distance unit to a time unit.  However if you can write the complete code in-line without a function in your example, please do so and maybe we can help you with the turning it into a function part.

Answer (score 0):

1. `int[] array2 = new int[2];` is useless here. 
   By the way, please do not name a variable "array" or "array2". It's hard to understand for others and for yourself in the future.
2. if you defined the "array"s length to 2, then this for loop `for(int i=0;i<numbers1.length;i++){...}` is meaningless cause you already defined that you can only have two integers in this array.
3. I do not know the meaning of "convert cm to milliseconds" since one is distance and the other is time...
4. I can not understand `(int a, int b)` what "a", "b" means.
   by my understanding the second code should be:

```
public static void timeTurn (int[] length) {
    int minMillsecond = 1000;
    int maxMillsecond = 3001;
    int gap = 33;
    for(int len : length){
        if (30 <= len <= 90){
            len += minMillsecond;
            while(len < 3000){ len+=gap;}
            print len;
        }
    }
}
```